# R shiny - Multiple data manipulation (e.g. merge, combine, deriving new columns, reset row values per condition) within reactive section

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to get some basic sense of putting all the data manipulation steps within the reactive session. The reason I have to do this is because the input files are reactive so they made all the new created data frames be reactive as well.

It is not working when outputting the combined dataset from 2 dynamic input sas datasets.

DAT_A:

```
A <- read.table(text = "
    ord, id, Score,DATE, VISIT
    1,001,23,2021-03-01,DAY 0
    2,001,26,2021-03-03,DAY 1
    3,001,45,2021-03-10,DAY 2
    4,001,41,2021-03-20,DAY 3
    5,001,67,2021-03-26,DAY 4", header = TRUE,sep = ",")
```

DAT_B:

```
DAT_B <- read.table(text = "
    ord, id, Weight,DATE
    1,002,100,2021-03-01
    2,002,100.5,2021-03-03
    3,002,101,2021-03-06
    4,002,103,2021-03-20
    5,002,102,2021-03-28", header = TRUE,sep = ",")
```

Shiny R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui<-fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("combine")
  )
  
))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  #dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  volumes <- getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input=input, 'dir', roots=volumes, session=session)
  path1 <- reactive({
    parseDirPath(volumes, input$dir)
  })
  
  
  DAT_A <- eventReactive(path1(), {
    DAT_A <- data.frame(haven::read_sas(paste0(path1(), "DAT_A.sas7bdat")))
    DAT_A
  })

  DAT_B <- eventReactive(path1(), {
    DAT_B <- data.frame(haven::read_sas(paste0(path1(), "DAT_B.sas7bdat")))
    DAT_B
  })
  
  
  output$combine = renderDT({
    
    c_all <- bind_rows(DAT_A(), DAT_B())
    
    head(c_all())
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can use `fileInput` to read in 2 SAS datasets and then `rbind` them.

Comment: @YBS, could you please provide the solution of sample code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one `fileInput` with `multiple=TRUE` or two separate ones with `multiple=FALSE`.  The code below shows the latter way to do it.

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)

ui<-fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("sasdata1", "Choose a SAS dataset", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".sas7bdat"),
    fileInput("sasdata2", "Choose a second SAS dataset", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".sas7bdat")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("combine")
  )
  
))

server <- function(input,output,session){

  DAT_A <- reactive({
    req(input$sasdata1)
    inData1 <- input$sasdata1
    if (is.null(inData1)){ return(NULL) }
    mydata1 <- haven::read_sas(inData1$datapath)
  })
  
  DAT_B <- reactive({
    req(input$sasdata2)
    inData2 <- input$sasdata2
    if (is.null(inData2)){ return(NULL) }
    mydata2 <- haven::read_sas(inData2$datapath)
  })
  
  output$combine = renderDT({
    
    c_all <- bind_rows(DAT_A(), DAT_B())
    
    #head(c_all())
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]